# Looking for inputs on my cookie/session authentication class, not sure if i got it correct

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

Im currently creating my own forum for my website and i have read plenty of topics on cookie/session authentication and i think im aware of the attacks etc that exists. I get that its not 100% secure but im trying to do it as safe as possible.

Im currently storing IP in the cookie and im aware that some might have problems with that but im going to change to check the first 2 blocks of the IP instead. I dont think its going to be a problem since 95% of the people in Sweden got broadband which rarely changes IP.

Something that im really insecure about is the session_start which i do need later for forms etc what is the best practice to implement it? im pretty sure that im doing that thing pretty much wrong.

Any inputs is much appreciated!

**Class**

```
class user2
{
    private $db = null;
    private $cookie_salt = '!!PLonSIMDSAM35324dfg5DAUSHODNASDJ353NMASDSA&%&A/SD&HASNJDdfghAS&DGIHYAUSDNA3535SDFASDF%A3532dfgsdfggsdg53532535SDGIASYDU';

    var $user_ip = false;
    var $user_id = false;
    var $user_username = false;
    var $cookie_identifier = false;
    var $user_logged_in = false;

    function __construct()
    {
        global $mysql_server;
        global $mysql_user;
        global $mysql_password;
        global $mysql_database_name;

        $this->db = new database($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database_name, true);

        $this->checkUserAuthentication();
    }


    public function Login($input_username, $input_user_password)
    {
        // If empty parameters return false
        if (empty($input_username) || empty($input_user_password))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $user_login = $this->db->q("SELECT user_id, username FROM `forum_user` WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1", 'ss' , $input_username, $input_user_password);
        if ($user_login != false)
        {
            $this->user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $this->user_id = $user_login[0]['user_id'];
            $this->user_username = $user_login[0]['username'];

            if($this->initiateSessionCookie() == true)
            {
                $this->user_logged_in = true;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function initiateSessionCookie()
    {
        // Delete old sessions from this user or USE REPLACE instead
        $this->db->q("DELETE FROM `forum_session` WHERE userid = ?", 'i' , $this->user_id);

        $identifier = md5($this->cookie_salt . md5($this->user_username . $this->user_ip) . $this->cookie_salt);
        $token = md5($this->generateToken());
        $timeout = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;  // 7 days
        $timeout_minutes = 10080; // 7 days
        $init_session = $this->db->q("INSERT INTO forum_session SET session = ? 
                                                                  , token = ? 
                                                                  , userid = ? 
                                                                  , sess_start = now() 
                                                                  , last_activity = now() 
                                                                  , sess_expire = DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL ? MINUTE) 
                                                                  , ip = ?", 'ssiis' , $identifier, $token, $this->user_id, $timeout_minutes, $this->user_ip);
        if($init_session != false) {
            setcookie('auth', "$identifier:$token", $timeout);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function generateToken()
    {
        $chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#&";

        for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
        {
            $rand_number = rand(0, 59);
            $random_string .= $chars[$rand_number];
        }
        return $random_string;
    }

    private function checkUserAuthentication()
    {
        $this->user_logged_in = false;

        list($_cookie_identifier, $_cookie_token) = explode(':', $_COOKIE['auth']);

        if(ctype_alnum($_cookie_identifier) && ctype_alnum($_cookie_token))
        {
            $_cookie_data['identifier'] = $_cookie_identifier;
            $_cookie_data['token'] = $_cookie_token;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        $auth_user = $this->db->q("SELECT * 
                                   FROM forum_session a 
                                   LEFT JOIN 
                                        forum_user b ON a.userid = b.user_id 
                                   WHERE 
                                        a.session = ? AND 
                                        a.token = ? 
                                   LIMIT 1", 'ss' , $_cookie_data['identifier'], $_cookie_data['token']);
        if($auth_user != false)
        {
            if(time() > strtotime($auth_user[0]['sess_expire']))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if($_cookie_data['identifier'] == md5($this->cookie_salt . md5($auth_user[0]['username'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . $this->cookie_salt))
            {
                $this->user_logged_in = true;

                $this->user_id = $auth_user[0]['user_id']; 
                $this->user_username = $auth_user[0]['username']; 
                $this->user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                return true;

                // TODO list
                // Renew token every 5 min? 
                // Renew cookie expire date
                // Renew session expire date
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function isUserLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->user_logged_in;
    }

}
```

The session handler which i include in all pages on the forum.

```
 require_once('classes/user2.class.php');
 $user = new User2();
 session_start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not start with session_start() in the controller(?).

If not needed always, I'd use a method in the controller so you avoid double session_start:

```
class controller {
  $sStarted = false;  

  function sStart() {
    if (!$this->sStarted) {
      session_start();
      $this->sStarted = true;
    }
```

regards
/t

Comment: Thanks for your input! will look into it :) is there anything else that looks dumb in the class?

Comment: Hi John, a bit late but anyway:
1. replace the globals. They're bad for you, initiate your class with a reference to your controller.
2. don't put the hash in a php-file if the php-file is in the www-root-scope. When your php-handler goes down (shit happens) your salt is exposed.